# What does a pipe in a macro signify?

Tags: c++

How is the following macro definition resolved?

```
#define EMAIL_SERVER_ADAPTER_FATAL_ERROR     MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1
```

I mean, is it resolved to 1 or to MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR and why?

Comment: That's not a "macro call". That's a "macro definition". So the question makes no sense.

Comment: @kerreksb the question makes perfect sense, in the context of the actual question title, what does `|` mean in the macro definition

Comment: @DanF I believe Kerrek was referring to the question in the post's body, which is "How is the call resolved ?".

Comment: Quite. I don't even read question titles once I've opened the post. The titles are summaries meant to let me decide on the main question index whether a question is interesting to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`|` has no special meaning in macros. The macro is resolved to

```
MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1
```

which is bitwise OR of two values (MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR and 1).

Comment: It also means that if you write `error_code & EMAIL_SERVER_ADAPTER_FATAL_ERROR` you'll "resolve" to `error_code & MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1`, which is not quite what you expected to have.

Comment: Oh yes. That turns out to be a dumb question after reading your answer. #define blindly replaces the text.

Comment: @Lyth Exactly. Should be replaced via `#define EMAIL_SERVER_ADAPTER_FATAL_ERROR    ( MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1 )`.

Answer (score 4):

The `|` in the macro has the same meaning as elsewhere in C and C++. It means bitwise or.

Presumable  `MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR` is some numeric value (otherwise it won't compile, pretty much).

For arguments sake, we'll make it 0x100

So the following code:

```
 return EMAIL_SERVER_ADAPTER_FATAL_ERROR;
```

will expand to:

```
 return MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1;
```

which in turn becomes:

```
 return 0x100 | 1;
```

which in turn is the same as:

```
 return 0x101;
```

Of course MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR is probably something other than 0x100 - but the principle still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are just text replacement, so

```
EMAIL_SERVER_ADAPTER_FATAL_ERROR
```

will be substituted for

```
MSB_RETURN_TYPE_FATAL_ERROR | 1
```

After that it is just numbers (i.e. plain bit-wise OR operation).